# Need help on display as jsp extension in web page using tridion web 8 and dd4t (version2)

Tags: dd4t, java, jsp

I am trying to display the page as .jsp instead of .html in the url but I run into issues. Any ideas or help would be great appreciate.

Everything is working fine with .html

1. In the tridion, i save my page as index2.jsp. it's using page template which have jsp extension.
2. I updated the web.xml to have

```xml
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
```

3. updated page controller

```java
@RequestMapping(value = { "/**/*.jsp","/**/*.html", "/**/*.txt", "/**/*.xml" }, method = { GET })
```

It throws error when i go to ../index.html or /indexjsp.jsp. If i remove the section in web.xml then it works fine

Did i do something wrong or missed anything? any suggestions would be great appreciate.

Thanks

Here is the error:

> at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166387/how-to-provide-support-for-urls-with-jsp-extension-in-spring (or this: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/3957-using-jsp-extension)

Comment: Hi Nuno,

Thanks for your help. I tried what they suggested and it still does not work but it

Comment: Hi Nuno,

Thanks for your help. I tried what they suggested and it still does not works. I think that is for the older Tomcat. I use the Tomcat version 8 so it's already set in conf/web.xml. I put this in the web.xml of my app
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/views/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

Since I remove <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern> in <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name> it does not shows the error anymore but the index2.jsp still does not dispatch.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is happening is that you are sending all `JSP` files through the `dispatcher`. The `dispatcher` then finds the `RequestMapping` attribute on the `PageContoller` and lets it try to handle the request.

This means that when Spring MVC requests a View, instead of being allowed to load the View, it is treated like a webpage. The `PageController` tries to resolve it from Tridion, instead of allowing the `ViewResolver` to load it from the file-system.

**In order of execution:**

1. You request `/index.jsp`, which is handled by the `PageController`
2. `PageController` (and subsequent method calls) determine the *Page Template* required is `/WEB-INF/views/homepage.jsp`
3. `/WEB-INF/views/homepage.jsp` is requested, as the associated *Page Template*, which is also (mistakenly) handled by the `PageController` due to greedy regex
4. Request for `/WEB-INF/views/homepage.jsp` returns a 404 as no such Page is published from Tridion

**Instead, do the following:**

In web.xml before your `dispatcher servlet-mapping` add the following, to send View requests to the View folder(s)

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/views/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

On your PageController specify the RequestMapping to handle the extensions you need

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/**/*.jsp", "/**/*.html", "/**/*.txt", "/**/*.xml" }, method = { GET })
```